# Why background color is different on the iphone screen?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Why is the background color where the cart is different on the iphone screen? How to solve ?

[image: Car image background color]

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-block d-md-none">
     <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
          <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="color: #fff;"></i>
                    
          <span class="badge badge-dark">0</span>
                    
           </a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you provide a simplest version of your code? can you also show how it is on android or desktop? I'd guess it's because it uses the default style of maybe a button (?), would be easier to help if you provide your code

Comment: Your HTML code was hidden because you did not format it as code. I fixed it by editing. Nevertheless, most probably, also your CSS is required to find the reason. And, which (background) color is wrong/expected?

Comment: I would like the background where the icon cart is not to be different. This behavior is only happening on my iphone screen. The computer screen is normal.

Comment: yeah but can you provide the image of the computer/android screen and also the css code? because I can't tell if it's because the css or it's because a default style is applied

Comment: Thank you guys. The problem was solved by removing the " type='button' " like Damzaky
said.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background of the Button to something that matches.

```
<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="color: #fff, background="######"></i>
```

You could look into IOS Color Schemes, You will find the colors there.

Comment: If any questions, Tag Me.